# Mode Interferometers (MMI) versus waveguide couplers

Tags: interferometry, photonics

In Photonics Integrated Circuits Mach-Zender (MZ) modulators are very often used. This design splits one wageguide into two spatially separated waveguides and makes them to rejoin, in order to recombine the two light beams. Often the method to split/recombine the MZI arms is to use Multi-Mode Interferometers (MMI). The two waveguides terminations are made inputs of a 2-to-1 MMI. Why is this method preferred instead of an EM field coupling approach? In other words, why aren’t the two waveguides simply made to become very close to each other so that the two beams can affect each other?

Answer (score 0):

In the absence of any answer at the moment, I can offer one based on this paper I found today [Optical multi-mode interference devices based on self-imaging: principles and applications](https://doi.org/10.1109/50.372474) . Words from this paper: "It is shown that multimode interference couplers offer superior performance, excellent tolerance to polarization and wavelength variations, and relaxed fabrication requirements when compared to alternatives such as directional couplers, adiabatic X- or Y-junctions, and diffractive star couplers."